# Selecting sum of first and last rows in related table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table I have these three tables:

Teams:

```
Id GUID UNIQUE PRIMARY
Name NVARCHAR
```

Participants:

```
Id GUID UNIQUE PRIMARY
FirstName NVARCHAR
[....]
TeamId GUID
```

ParticipantData:

```
Id GUID UNIQUE PRIMARY
Weight FLOAT
Date DATETIME
ParticipantId GUID
TeamId GUID
```

What I need is an SQL query that gives me all columns from Teams AND:

- The sum of the first (order by Date) entries in ParticipantData of participants in the team (TeamId)
- The sum of the last (ordered by Date) entries in ParticipantData of participants in the team (TeamId)

Explanation:

I have lots of participants (team members) reporting their weight with some interval (Weight + Date). What I'm trying to accomplish is to calculate the weight loss of all the team members.

> On 2019-01-03 Participant 1 reports Weight 78
>
> On 2019-01-06 Participant 1 reports Weight 75
>
> On 2019-01-04 Participant 2 reports Weight 86
>
> On 2019-01-07 Participant 2 reports Weight 83
>
> I need the query to get SumOfFirstWeights (78 + 86) = 164
>
> I need the query to get SumOfLastWeights (75 + 83) = 158

Which gives me a weight loss of 6.

I've tried many combinations of:

```
Select *, 
(SELECT TOP (1) Sum(Weight) 
 FROM ParticipantData WHERE (TeamId = Teams.Id) 
 GROUP BY ParticipantId
)
ORDER BY Date As SumOfFirstWeights 
From Teams
```

Comment: Could you add your attempts please?

Comment: What did you try? Could you please also provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: @Sami didn't I describe the expected result? If not please tell me what is unclear to you.

Comment: Sample data and expected result is more or less standard requirements for a question like this and if you don't get it, expected result is the result you expect to get from the posted sample data

Comment: There's no such definition last row or first row (although internally each record has *row id*). You need to be specific to differentiate one from another - i.e. *context*. For instance, you have ten dates - from January, 1 to January, 10. In this case first of January is *first* row and 10-th of January is *last* row.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson maybe I've been working long hours, but I believe I've describe my tables, what results I need (weight loss based on data from ParticipantData) and I also showed my own (incorrect) SQL attempt. What more do you need?

Comment: @JohnyL as described in the question FIRST ROW is the first entry by each ParticipantId order by the Date column and LAST ROW is the last entry ordered by DATE DESC

Comment: I don't see why this was closed either.

Comment: I was writing an answer using windowing functions

Comment: Haha. So was I :-)

Comment: `FIRST_VALUE(Weight) OVER (ORDER BY Date PARTITION BY ParticipantID RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS First_Weight,` etc

Comment: Thanks, Hogan. I've many years experience with SQL querying for webpages, but I've never seen anything like that before. How do I implement that in "SELECT Id, Name From Teams..."?

Comment: Can participants switch teams or why is `TeamId` in `ParticipantData`?

Comment: @stickybit No, I only include the TeamId to make the query more simple. The query is intended for at list of teams. When I have the working query I'll change it to get the team sums from a subquery with ParticipantId (..."WHERE ParticipantId In (Select ParticipantId From Participants Where TeamId = Teams.Id))"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is some kind of greatest/lowest per group, moreover, you want a sum of these values.

```
select t.id, t.name, sum(t1.weight), sum(t2.weight)
from teams t
left join
(
    select pd.teamid, pd.participantid, pd.weight
    from ParticipantData pd
    join 
    (
        select teamid, participantid, min(date) min_date
        from ParticipantData 
        group by teamid, participantid
    ) t on pd.teamid = t.teamid and 
           pd.participantid = t.participantid and
           pd.date = t.min_date
) t1 on t.id = t1.teamid
left join 
(
    select pd.teamid, pd.participantid, pd.weight
    from ParticipantData pd
    join 
    (
        select teamid, participantid, max(date) max_date
        from ParticipantData 
        group by teamid, participantid
    ) t on pd.teamid = t.teamid and 
           pd.participantid = t.participantid and
           pd.date = t.max_date
) t2 on t1.teamid = t2.teamid and
        t1.participantid = t2.participantid
group by t.id, t.name
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed! One thing: the query only returns rows from Teams where the sums is not null. Can it return all the teams but with 0 or null in the sum columns if no data in ParticipantData?

Comment: @Mads I believe that can be achieved if you use `LEFT JOIN` (I have updated the answer)

Comment: I tried that myself, but I guess I did not edit them all. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the first and last row per team. You can use analytic functions for this. I'm using `ROW_NUMBER` which gives me exactly one record, even if a participant has two entries on the same day.

```
with pd as
(
  select
    participantid,
    weight,
    row_number() over (partition by participantid order by date) as one_is_first,
    row_number() over (partition by participantid order by date desc) as one_is_last
  from participantdata
)
, team_weights as
(
  select
    p.teamid,
    sum(case when pd.one_is_first = 1 then weight end) as first_weight,
    sum(case when pd.one_is_last = 1 then weight end) as last_weight,
    sum(case when pd.one_is_last = 1 then weight end) -
    sum(case when pd.one_is_first = 1 then weight end) as difference
  from pd
  join participant p on p.id = pd.participantid
  where (pd.one_is_first = 1 or pd.one_is_last = 1)
  group by p.teamid
)
select *
from teams
join team_weights on where team_weights.team_id = teams.id
order by teams.id;
```